# JQuery selector ID start but not finish with

Tags: jquery, selector

Do you know how to select elements which id DOES NOT contain a given string?
Or to select elements which id DOES NOT contain a given word?

Example:

```
<div id="my_div">
    <div id="tab_abcd">...</div>
    <div id="tab_efgh">...</div>
    <div id="tab_jklm">...</div>
    <div id="tab_nopq">...</div>
    <div id="tab_rstu">...</div>
    <div id="tab_vwxy">...</div>
</div>
```

I want to select the div that starts with "tab_" but doesn't not finish with "nopq". Cannot use nt-child because these div are generated dynamically: so, I don't know the order.

Comment: The answers below are great.  But if you have control over the generated html, you may want to consider tagging the divs with a 'class' and then selecting it that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('[id^="tab"]:not([id$="nopq"])')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/yB44A/

Comment: and we can add many not if we need like: $('[id^="tab"]:not([id$="nopq"]):not([id$="rstu"])')

Comment: @Yoong Kim: yep, `[...]` or `:not()` selectors are the same as `.classname` and `#id`, so you can chain them as you want

Answer (score 3):

using [starts-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), [not](http://api.jquery.com/not/) and [ends-with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="tab_"]').not('div[id$="nopq"]').each(function(){
    // whatever
});
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/jyGej/)

Comment: maybe this works but in my case, I have other selector inside, my final code is: $('[id^="details_product_"]:not([id$="functiontestreports"]) a[name^="togglePhoto_"]').trigger('click');

Answer (score 2):

You can try this purpose:

```
$('div:not([id*="given word"])')
```

Comment: "doesn't not finish with "nopq"" - `*=` would cause false-positives

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[id^="tab_"]:not(div[id$="nopq"])');
```

Check [JQAPI Documentation](http://jqapi.com) for more info on selectors and examples.